# Magnetic sliding effect when hovering on <a> tag

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am trying to re-create the "magnetic" effect on hovering it is possible to see in the Tesla's [home page](https://www.tesla.com) in the Header section.

I do understand how to re-create the glass effect, using some transparency and some `:hover` effects. However, I have no clue on ow to re-create that kind of sliding magnet effect.

Is there a solution using pure CSS/Tailwind.js?

Adding a .gif to better show what I mean.[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm adapting something from https://codepen.io/rm/pen/AXpmja . The idea is an element that's margined from left in differently under each menu item.

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  display: block;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  padding: .75rem 0;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.two:hover~hr {
  margin-left: 25%;
}

.three:hover~hr {
  margin-left: 50%;
}

.four:hover~hr {
  margin-left: 75%;
}

hr {
  height: 2rem;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 128, 128, 0.25);
  pointer-events: none;
  position: relative;
  top: -36px;
  border: none;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li class="one"><a href="#">Uno</a></li>
    <li class="two"><a href="#">Dos</a></li>
    <li class="three"><a href="#">Tres</a></li>
    <li class="four"><a href="#">Quatro</a></li>
    <hr />
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What is I have n <li> items? The seems kind of hardcoded solution (don't get me wrong, just asking :-) ). In addition, this starts with an underline on the first element, however, there should not be any "hover" effect on page load. Anyway, thanks a lot for you answer and time!